# lifecycle of Service

Tags: android

In my activity I implement `onstop()`,`onstart()`,`onstart()`

I start and bind my service. My service extends `IntentService`
so `onStop()` I just call `unbindService()`.

Then I go Settings of my device and open Running tab-> show cached processes
I see that:

1. when a touch back key. in show cached processes my service has still.
2. when a touch home key. in show cached processes my service has gone.

Both of them call `onstop()`.

So can anybody can tell me why there have 2 cases like this? Or is this is a misunderstanding about the lifecycle of `Service` and `Activity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you why there are 2 cases like that. However, I can tell you that whether a service is cached or not by the Android OS is not dependent on what button you use to call onStop(). The decision to cache a process is made by the OS depending on how much memory is needed by the service and how often you use it among several other factors.

To quote Google on this matter: " It may cache processes that you’ve been using recently in RAM, so they restart more quickly when you open them again, but it will erase the cache if it needs the RAM for new activities." [1]

[1] - http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=168921

Comment: So when a service go to cache processes, it's stopped and cache process just store somethings in oncreate() of service !!!